# Install .apk without Activity or Dialog

Tags: android, android-install-apk

My app downloads an .apk and installs it using an activity like this:
[Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

However, it causes a dialog to appear and requires user action. So my question is:

Is there a way to programatically without requiring user interaction?

Based on the comments I have to provide additional information:

- Yes, there are security implications. I just want to know if it is possible.
- Actually, I do own their phone.

Comment: NOoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo please do not do this.  You dont own their phone, let them decide

Comment: Try reading through this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission/5805299#5805299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to programatically without requiring user interaction?

Not unless you are writing custom firmware.

Comment: I upvote this answer because it is the right answer and it tells you how to achieve what the OP asks(by writing custom firmware^_^).

Answer (score 5):

No, you can not do this, the user must approve all app installs.

Since it is your device, however, you can use adb to install it without a dialog! ;)