# Android Install apk using busybox command-line

Tags: android, command-line, installation, apk, busybox

I want to install apk silently in android phone, I have found this solution  [(Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission), is how to install apk using busybox command line, but when i tape busybox install path/to/apkfile, it does not work, can someone help me by giving some examples please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command line program that does this is `pm`: package manager. So try `pm install apkfile`
If you run the command with no arguments it will print out some help text. I don't know how silent it will be - but then you should not be hiding installs from the end user anyway.

Comment: Thank you for responce, yes i will use pm, it is a god methode too, thank you very much.