# Allow Automatic updating feature for private distributed android app

Tags: android, android-intent, autocomplete, installation, android-manifest

For my private distributed android app, I am checking whether any update is available, from my distribution server using some web service every time user opens the app. If any update is available I am downloading the latest apk to SD card and there by calling below Intent. It will installs the new version.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

At the time of installation, it is showing Replace Application Dialog with a message "The application you are installing will replace another application. All previous user data will be saved." with "OK" and "cancel" options. Instead of showing that Replace application dialog, I want something like update and cancel or allow automatic updating option just like some apps on android market providing. How to do it, plz give any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install apps silently, with granted INSTALL_PACKAGES permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)

Comment: @GrahamBorland U mean to say for this feature my app needs android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES but Android does not grant that permission to 3rd party apps. So it is not possible for normal developers.Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can reach this using http://push-link.com. It have a lot of nice features.

There is a method called PushLink.idle which "enable/disable" automatic updates.