# How can i Install apps silently on android ?? without permission from the user?

Tags: android, permissions, installation, android-install-apk, silent-installer

How can i Install apps silently on android ?? without permission from the user ?

i have read this   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)  , but i didn't get the idea for correct answer for this question which relate to PackageInstaller ???

On otherhand,  i take a look to this  [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)  , i have test it ,but still need permission from user to complete the installation !!!!

**am not gonna to build virus , i just do that for research issues for android security**

Comment: as far as I know you cannot do so without permission of the user.

Comment: Fortunately, this is not possible, unless your application (that wants to do the installing) is signed as part of the system firmware or is part of the system firmware.

Comment: how can i make it as  system firmware

Comment: Is requiring root access to rooted phones an option?

Comment: give me help link to more info for this requirement cause i didn't get what's you mean ??

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this on a stock device. The only way to get an apk file into data/app/ is via the PackageManager.apk and the only way within that component to do it is for the user to press the intall button.

The system was built specifically to dissallow the type of behaviour that you are trying to use.

If you are running your own customized version of the OS on your own device then you are free to tinker with the system source code that enforces this behavior to try to skirt around it. But I imagine you have a very difficult task ahead of you if you want to try.

If your device is rooted, you could paste the apk into the data/app/ folder which would install it. But the user is still going to have a chance to deny, because the Super User permission pop-up will be shown.

Comment: I agree. I will also add, that some people just don't read the Permissions an app wants, so a lot of times, any security vulnerabilities can't even be controlled by Android. It definitely gets mitigated by the sandbox approach.