# How to do a silent install (from inside an android device that's ROOTED)

Tags: android, apk, root, silent-installer

I'm currently trying to find some way of pragmatically installing updates onto a device using an Android that:

- has no means of user input
- has no internet or network
- Is running Android 4.0

This is why I am looking to do it silently. Worst case would be hooking it up to a PC every time I wish to update but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Input is from an external sdcard.

From what I've found so far there seems to a couple of ways that will, apparently, work:

- [Root set the chmod to 777 on the /data/app (and not care about security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)
- appbrain over the web (Useless to me)
- Write / Rewrite the OS (Past my expertise)

So my question is as follows:

What programs do I need in order to do this and how do I go about doing it?

Comment: How does the "file" get onto the SD card?

Comment: You can simply copy the APK to the sdcard, then hava a script that runs continuously checking the existence of the APK (sleeping) and when detected run `adb install /mnt/sdcard/my.apk`. That's it!

Comment: adb install didn't work from within an app thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how and what I used for people that have the same problem.

- Firstly I have installed busybox (Seems I needed this to do install as both pm and adb calls didnt work)
- Install Terminal Emulator (So I could check commands worked and using chmod on phone)
- Run Terminal and type su -s

Now that the Terminal shows # instead of $ I can now give permission to what I need to do my install.

Now from my app I can call install using busybox.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/busybox install " + ToInstall.getAbsolutePath() + " /system/app");
```

In my case the ToInstall is a file I have located from a device.

**Note:**

This installs weirdly I have to use the following to remove

```
rm /system/app/AppName
```

Also its looks weird but doesn't matter as I won't have a screen

Permission on busy box path may need to be set in order for this to work.
I can do this from the terminal in su mode. 702 is said to work although I used 777 as not worried about security.

```
 chmod 702 system/bin/busybox
```

Comment: No! 777 permissions are outrageously insecure.  They let anyone trojan things.  DO NOT DO THIS.

Comment: There we go chris manage to do it without chmod 777 just fixed the answer to relect this