# Android - update of custom preinstalled app

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am creating an app that will be preinstalled on Android phones manufactured by my business partner. This app will not be published on Google Play.

Is there a convenient way of performing updates of that application without user interaction (download APK in background and install it without prompting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES (which requires your app to be within /system/app or signed by the manufacturer), then you can have a look at [this question about installing apps silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission), there are multiple ways how to do that. Probably the most easy way is downloading the apk, and executing `pm install /path/to/apk`.

Comment: Thanks dst, I will definately look into that