# Background update/upgrade of custom Android application [not using com.android.vending]

Tags: upgrade, android

Context:
Earlier this year Facebook updated their android app without using the google play services : http://liliputing.com/2013/03/facebook-pushes-android-update-to-enable-silent-updates-bypassing-the-play-store.html

I would like to try a similar thing with my android app.
(I'm aware of the implications so please don't post regarding the same.)

Description:
I have gone through the the related Android classes Package Manager - [Androidxref](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/) and resources like: [Install apps silently, with granted INSTALL_PACKAGES permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission) but could not find any non-rooted method.
Ways like:

```
   public static int installAPP(String absolutePath){
        int status = -1;
        File file = new File(absolutePath); 
        if(file.exists()){
            try {   
                String command = "adb install -r " +  StringUtil.insertEscape(absolutePath);
                Process install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
                status = install.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Not Installed!");
            } finally { return status;}
         }
      }
```

works just fine, but then again it's for rooted devices.

Any information/hints for possible ways of doing and and any relevant information/hacks regarding the same is much appreciated.
Thank You.

PS. I am working on a ROM.

Comment: If you are working on a ROM, then you can install your own stuff as you see fit, because your system apps can hold `INSTALL_PACKAGES`.

Comment: Dear Mark, Thanks for the information and also for being so actively supportive to the community [github && so].

If I weren't working on the ROM will there be any feasibility of achieving the same. Any pointer on how facebook was able to achieve it ?