# Custom Android apps market

Tags: android, google-play, rom

I'm new here at SO (long time reader)

I'm a developper (soft, web, mobile) and I have a specific request.

I got approched by a friend who works for a mobile phone carrier, and asked me if I can develop for them a custom Android market for the stock phones they sell to their customers (mainly low cost Android smartphones and tablets) for local (country) developped apps.

It's a big project involving a server side (THE market) and a client side (the android app).

For the server side, I've got no problem since it's a standard, common thing.

Now I'm studying the feasability of the client (the app) and my vision is not clear...

- First, I will get the support of the manufacturer which is good.

*Now correct me if I'm wrong*

- I think the app will be a sys app
- The app should be signed with the ROM key (obtained from manufacturer) so it could install APKs bypassing Android secuity (not sure if it's enough though).
- The app will have INSTALL_PACKAGES* authorisation (among others).
- The app will call pm install package (so it'll display the package authorisations) .. not sure about this too.
- How about pakages updates ??
- Finally I'll send the app to the manufacturer to include it in the ROM.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: This is a big understanding which I don't think you understand nor grasp the concepts of, and can't be explained even in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I think who downvoted the question don't understand it... I'm not a noob and I consider myself an experimented developper, I already developed tens of android apps. I didnt ask for code or anything, just a direction...

Comment: @nadjibus I think then you misunderstand the purpose of this website.  We don't discuss, we answer.  Unless you have code to back up something you're talking about, you are likely to get "too broaded."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I think the app will be a sys app

Yes, that would probably be best.

> The app should be signed with the ROM key (obtained from manufacturer) so it could install APKs bypassing Android secuity (not sure if it's enough though).

The only way for an app to be a system app is to sign it with the system key. I expect the carrier (not manufacturer unless they're the same/working very close together) will not give it to you. Generally what happens is that you give them the unsigned APK and they sign it on their side before deploying.

> The app will have Install_apk authorisation (among others).

I assume you mean [`INSTALL_PACKAGES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_PACKAGES). Only for silent installs. Otherwise you don't need this permission.

> The app will call pm install package (so it'll display the package authorisations) .. not sure about this too.

I expect not. This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission) might help you. You'll want to just open the APK in the general installation case as you want the user to see the normal installation dialog.

> How about pakages updates ??

What about them? Also, this is somewhere you might want silent installs, but you don't want to do it blindly.

> Finally I'll send the app to the manufacturer to include it in the ROM.

Sure.

Is it feasible? Sure, plenty of other people do it. If you want anything more, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you kabuko for your answer. "I assume you mean INSTALL_PACKAGES. Only for silent installs. Otherwise you don't need this permission." -> so you mean I'll just create an intent and fire the activity, Android then takes place ? will it display the permissions dialog ? same thing for updates ?