# Neither user 10051 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, permissions, system

My project has a problem of Silent Installation. my project need the permission `"android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"`,but the permission is system permission. How to use this permission？

```
error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10051 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` has added uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"`

Comment: Your app requests that permission, but Android does not grant that permission to 3rd party apps. See LogCat for permission related logs [Something related here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)

Answer (score 1):

This permission is only given to system apps. In order to get this permission, your app:

1) must be signed with the system certificates. These certificates are generally available only to the device manufacturers.

2) be installed in /system/app partition.

Comment: Do I need to have both of these or any one of these? I am on Android Oreo