# Application installation failed

Tags: android

I'm trying to write my first android app, I have alreadu managed to test it and debug on my Tablet which runs Android 4.4 but I couldn't run it on my mobile phone which runs Android 5.1.1
I googled it everywhere but I couldn't find any solution.. I have downloaded A-L-L SDK files (costed me about 60 GB) and still nothing works..
The main error is this:

[image]

on the Run console it says this:

```
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/yarden4.myappsname
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.
```

here is a logcat cropped to the specific time where I try to run:

```
12-16 03:19:16.543 16411-16411/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-16 03:19:16.547 16411-16411/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
12-16 03:19:16.653 16411-16411/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
12-16 03:19:16.660 16411-16411/? E/Pm: Error
                                       java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.
                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1553)
                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1505)
                                           at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.installPackageAsUser(IPackageManager.java:3033)
                                           at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.runInstall(Pm.java:958)
                                           at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.run(Pm.java:143)
                                           at com.android.commands.pm.Pm.main(Pm.java:101)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249)
12-16 03:19:16.662 16411-16411/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 1
12-16 03:19:16.662 16411-16411/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 1.
```

I also tried: reinstalling android studio / searching for the app installed somehow on my phone (its nor in app list and nor in data/app folders) / messing with google play service app.. / tried different apps.. even a clean neat hello world won't run.. and I'll mention again.. it works fine on my tablet.

P.S my phone and tablet are rooted + xposed + non original ROMs (both)

any idea what to do? I'm stuck for days with this thing.. :(

Thanks ALOT ahead!

Comment: Just curious, why did you download all the SDK tools? The minimum you need is the API you are targeting. The max is anything above that - you don't even need the latest unless you are developing for it specifically.

Comment: Also, see the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453942/neither-user-10051-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-install-packages)

Comment: Downloading SDk's blindly doesn't make any sense ,Before doing anything must read the respective document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I don't quite sure what was exactly the problem but I have managed to solve it.

The solution was to switch ROM.. :\
I just flashed a different ROM from the same version, pretty much the same.. I didn't even wipe anything so I left with everything I had.. but that fixed it..

I Hope that might help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line in your permissions, in your `Android manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

If the problem remains:
- Clean and rebuild
- Check if your phone didn't have some permissions turned off

You can finally give a look to this link if none of the solutions above are working:
[Permission is only granted to system app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app/13802178#13802178)

Comment: Wow I had so much hope and none of the above worked!! :/ 
first of all, I tried cleaning.. I tried the simple 'hello world' app. it gave the same error.
also the permission for INSTALL_PACKAGES is for system apps.. I don't need that permission on my app and it gave an error when I tried to add that..
I also tried the link showing how to avoid that error and even though it removed the warning it still didn't fix the problem..
And for @cricket_007: I tried all SDK to be 100% sure thats not it, as im not quite sure what is everything there..
and also your link didn't help either :((

Answer (score 0):

If you are here because you rename your project directory and gotten the following error:

[image]

The solution is to simply go to menu > Build > Clean Project. Then, click run app (the green arrow).

This will force the project to clean up those build at `app/build` which i think is causing problem.