# Install apk silently without rooted device

Tags: android

Is it possible to install an apk file silently without the device being rooted? Most of the posts on this subject in Stackoverflow are somewhat outdated and it isn't clear whether the newer version of Android (Kit Kat) has support for this.

Comment: I am also interested in this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install apps silently, with granted INSTALL\_PACKAGES permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)

Comment: @BhaveshJethani That's very outdated, like by 3 years.

Comment: The answer is no. And you can bet it will remain that way. Last thing the world needs are apps silently installed that spy on users.

Answer (score 0):

Copy10 /androrat. This does exist and happens. Embedding apk into image and sending it to the victim. Usually a buffer overflow in readong the rule is what gets it running and then its on there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).