# How can I get anoter app B installed when I call a funcion of app A?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, permissions

there's an app A installed on on my phone. when I call a funcion in A ,app B get installed and started. (That means B hasn't been installed! I only have the apk file of B!)

during this, no asking for perminssion to install, making it seems only app A was running.

Is this possible?how do I write my app A?

background:what I'm tying to do is code offloading,letting B's compution migrantted to another phone with app A controlling this process smoothly.So that two phones can work together.

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)

Comment: @MahaKhan  really thank you, I'm reading it