# AUTO-UPDATE Android app

Tags: android, mobile, auto-update

I need to have a mechanism where an app auto-updates itself without any user interaction. The app is an off the shelf app (off market).
Updates should happen in background without any click.
How can we achieve this?

Comment: If "update" is modifying src or res then you cannot. This kind of update basically uninstalls previous version and installs current version.

Comment: Installing current version will still ask the user to accept it. I want no user interaction. Is it possible?

Comment: no it's not possible. User must submit that he understand apps permissions and agree to install it. 
It's possible to do that on root phones. How do you want to deliver then apk to users phone?

Comment: TestFairy does it... but never in background. Remember @Harsh asked about a non-market app.

Comment: In TestFairy user need to install the app.

Comment: check this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission

Comment: On way can be downloading the apk from the server and then unzipping it. Is there a way to unpackage the apk from SD Card?

Comment: @Harsh you mean the user should not install the app even once in your case? Come on. You asked about "auto-update",. You know how TestFairy works, right? You install the APK *once* and it updates, if needed, when launched...

Comment: @AndrewV. tried the above answer. User still needs to click on Install. My requirement says "no clicks".

Comment: @ shkschneider When we upload a build on testfairy we can invite the testers via email. The user still have to go to email and install it. I need to bypass that process

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices or via your own custom ROM. Apps cannot install or update any apps (their own app or the apps of others) without user involvement.

Comment: How is it possible on a rooted phone? Is there any code for the same?

Comment: Was able to auto update app using adb commands via su on a rooted device.

Comment: Was able to auto update app using adb commands via su on a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible, and don't need to be rooted. You only need to have a signed apk, and execute it in background.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(externalStorageDir, dir+ "APP.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The user will be prompted while installing, because we should inform the privileges of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. Final solution was it cannot be done phones which are not rooted. On rooted phone we can run adb script to do so. While on un rooted phone we can download the apk in background and launch the installer activity that will ask user to click once to approve installing the apk.