# Andorid: install an app from another one silently (without Root)

Tags: android, installation, root, app-secret

I want to make a prank to a frinend.
I m coding an application that send an SMS to my phone saying something. The problem is that when my friend installs my app the device obviously alert him saying that the app has the "send SMS" permission and it may cost him money.
My task is to code a second fake application that downloads silently the real app (the one that send SMS to me) and install it silently too. Without asking him to agree all that permissions.
The phone of my friend is not rooted.

Is it possible to reach my task?? If yes, could you give me some advice on what I should do , or link some tutorials ?

Comment: The android security model prohibits this.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to reach my task?

Fortunately, no, to prevent malware authors from doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip. No obviously my task is just for fun, not for bad purpouse of course

Comment: not possible i try to do this for one of my project http://www.mobile-spy.com/ but i failed check out this thread for more clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission

Comment: @SahirSaiyed And is possible to hide just the send SMS permission??
I m afraid to know the answer :(

Comment: @AlessioTrecani here's a good exercise; ask yourself this: Would I want a bad guy being able to hide the SMS permission when I install their app? SPOILER: no.