# The correct way to install apks from system app?

Tags: android, package-management

I'm developing Kiosk Mode app, that should automatically update another app.

The first app is system (pre-installed to /system/app). The second one should not be system app.

I want to update the second app from the first (first downloads the second from server) silently. There is no SuperUser on the device (but first app is system).

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: On Android 5.0+, I'd look into the device owner stuff, as I think this is covered in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)