# android download and update application then unistall old version and install new version from service

Tags: android, installation

I want to check version my application then if new version is available ,download this new file and then uninstall old version and install new version.
i have a web service witch hosted a 'json' file witch contain version and download path. until  now ,i successfully download json and read the version and download path.and i used [this link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-update-application.html) to do it. but i have problem with this code because during download new version a Chooser piker appears with ask me to choose an application with alert title "complete action using" . now after reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog), i have couple of questions:
1)I'm doubted that did i used correct method or not ?
2) which method should i use? is my application download link a service or not ?
3)after download the new version how can i delete current version and install new version ?

I will appreciate if anyone help me .i worked on this matter for a week and i do not succeed.

Comment: my problem is ,when i use mentioned link. downloading did not work and "complete action using" dialog appears. i don't know why.I'm confused that according to described situation ,is using mentioned link a right method to my end?

Answer (score -1):

you can not install apk on device if you dont have root access with code.
if you have root access then you can install apk silently with code 
follow below thread 
[Install apps silently, with granted INSTALL_PACKAGES permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)

Comment: you can install apps easily with intents

Comment: for installing apps silently, you need root access