# update application from USB flash drive

Tags: android, usb

I need to update multiple applications installed on many Android devices.

Is there anyway to put theirs updated apks on USB flash drive, write some script that updates them and run this script manually after I plug it to the device?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most basic question would be why? Is this something you are purposely keeping off the app store? If it is not TOS breaking just pay the 25$ for a dev account and you can even just keep it in a beta/alpha status so only people you allow to can download it.
Beyond that Android phones can install APK's from third party sources, host the APK somewhere or get it to the user in some fashion and they can download from the phone and install.
Really the app store is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use case and control of the devices that you are updating. Using an OTA update tool is always the fastest option for getting upgrades out. You can use BETA distribution, or TestFairy, or even hockey app, however, if you are not choosing to use these items then you will need to do a little extra leg work. Don't worry I won't patronize you with "why are you doing this", you asked a question so I'll do my best to answer it.

1) Register a service or app who's whole goal is to update others. Maybe you call it updateService.

2) Register a Broadcast Receiver for the updateService that listens for USB connected

3) Read the contents of the USB stick to know what needs to be updated. Possibly a folder system where you check "if folder exists, then update" or you can keep a local sql db of update service ownership that keeps track of last updates or current versions.

4) Once you see what needs installed have your service run ADB Install commands. However, if you have new permissions added then user interaction would be required unless you have root access or system level privelages on your update service.

Here is a package installer thread that will give you some ideas of how to silently update. [Install apps silently, with granted INSTALL_PACKAGES permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission)

So the short answer is, yes you can do it, but the longer answer is revolving around the type of control you have, and if you have root or system level access and how much leg work is it worth to you. If you are ok with User Interactions on install then you won't have to worry as much, but I'm guessing you want silent installations.

Hope that helps.