# Install custom apps or apps from google play store in Work Profile programmatically

Tags: android, device-policy-manager, android-management-api, android-managed-profile

I want to install custom apps or apps from google play store in `Work Profile` without user interaction. It can be done using [Android Device Policy app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc) and [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) remotely only for play store apps.

I've created custom `Work Profile` application referring to [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicManagedProfile) in android using `DevicePolicyManager` and `DeviceAdminReceiver`.

I'm able to enable or disable System apps in my `Work Profile` using:

```
packageFlags = PackageManager.MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, packageFlags);
if (0 == (applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_INSTALLED)) {
    if (enabled) {
        devicePolicyManager.enableSystemApp(componentName, packageName);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot disable this app: " + packageName);
        return;
    }
} else {
    devicePolicyManager.setApplicationHidden(componentName, packageName, !enabled);
}
```

But I can't find any method to install play store apps or any custom apps (.apk files) in my `work profile`, the way it is done using `Android Management API` and `Android Device Policy app`. Is there any way to do it programmatically?

Comment: User interaction is needed for install apk.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani updated my question please check.

Comment: I did't remember exactly but this can be done by using something Playstore for Enterprise

Comment: https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/enterprise/employees/

Comment: yeah using Android Management API we can do it. But I want to create my custom Device Policy Controller with that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission/5805299